# Yearly roll-up of student AD accounts

Tags: powershell

I have created an automated script on a made up server that will be run once a year the intention is students within a year level to transfer to the next year and add the new memberships whilst deleting the old year level.

This issue is that when I separate the script into 3 scripts it works without any issues. but, when I amalgamate them into the same PowerShell script the profiles don't move to the new OU all the memberships change.

```
 import-module ActiveDirectory 

 $properties = @('Name', 'Enabled', 'HomeDirectory', 'DistinguishedName')
 $dc = 'DC1.unisa.local'                                                             # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''

 $our = 'OU=test 1,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                    # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $ou1 = 'OU=test 2,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $ou2 = 'OU=test 3,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $ou3 = 'OU=test 4,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $ou4 = 'OU=test 5,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $ou5 = 'OU=test 6,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $ou6 = 'OU=test 7,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $oud = 'OU=del,OU=USR,DC=unisa,DC=local'                     # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupNamer = 'Reception'                                                                      # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupName1 = 'Year1'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupName2 = 'Year2'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupName3 = 'Year3'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupName4 = 'Year4'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupName5 = 'Year5'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupName6 = 'Year6'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupNamed = 'Disabled Account'                                                               # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupNames = 'Students'                                                                       # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupNameu = 'Users1'                                                                          # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 $adGroupNamesu = 'Sophos User'                                                                   # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ''
 Start-Transcript -OutputDirectory "\\dc1\SYSVOL\unisa.local\scripts"                                   # EDIT LINE BETWEEN -> ""

 ##DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE - DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE - DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE - DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE##



 ###############################################################################################################################################
 $adUserIdsr = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($our) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIds1 = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou1) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIds2 = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou2) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIds3 = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou3) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIds4 = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou4) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIds5 = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou5) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIds6 = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($ou6) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name
 $adUserIdsd = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -SearchBase ($oud) -Properties $properties | Select-object $properties | Sort-Object Name

foreach($adUsersd in $adUserIds6)
     {
     $adGroupMembershipd = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc

     $radGroup6 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName6
     $radGroups = Get-ADGroup $adGroupNames
     $radGroupu = Get-ADGroup $adGroupNameu
     $radGroupsu = Get-ADGroup $adGroupNamesu

     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsersd.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroup6.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroup6.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsersd.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroups.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroups.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsersd.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroupu.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroupu.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsersd.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroupsu.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroupsu.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     "Disabling Active Directory user account $($adUsersd.Name)"
     Disable-ADAccount -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsersd.Name) to the retired group"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsersd.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $oud
     }

foreach($adUsers6 in $adUserIds5)
     {
     $adGroupMembership6 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsers6.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc

     $adGroup6 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName6
     $radGroup5 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName5

     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsers6.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroup5.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers6.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroup5.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     if($adGroupMembership6 -like $($adGroup6.Name))
         {
         "$adUsers6.Name is alreay a member of group $($adGroup6.Name)"
         }
      else
         {
         "Adding Active Directory user $($adUsers6.Name) the the global security group $($adGroup6.Name)"
         Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers6.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($adGroup6.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
         }
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsers6.Name) to next year level"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsers6.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $ou6
     }

foreach($adUsers5 in $adUserIds4)
     {
     $adGroupMembership5 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsers5.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc
     $adGroup5 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName5
     $radGroup4 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName4

     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsers5.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroup4.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers5.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroup4.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     if($adGroupMembership5 -like $($adGroup5.Name))
         {
         "$adUsers5.Name is alreay a member of group $($adGroup5.Name)"
         }
      else
         {
         "Adding Active Directory user $($adUsers5.Name) the the global security group $($adGroup5.Name)"
         Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers5.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($adGroup5.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
         }
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsers5.Name) to next year level"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsers5.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $ou5
     }

foreach($adUsers4 in $adUserIds3)
     {
     $adGroupMembership4 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsers4.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc
     $adGroup4 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName4
     $radGroup3 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName3
     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsers4.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroup3.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers4.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroup3.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     if($adGroupMembership4 -like $($adGroup4.Name))
         {
         "$adUsers4.Name is alreay a member of group $($adGroup4.Name)"
         }
      else
         {
         "Adding Active Directory user $($adUsers4.Name) the the global security group $($adGroup4.Name)"
         Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers4.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($adGroup4.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
         }
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsers4.Name) to next year level"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsers4.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $ou5
     }

foreach($adUsers3 in $adUserIds2)
     {
     $adGroupMembership3 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsers3.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc
     $adGroup3 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName3
     $radGroup2 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName2
     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsers3.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroup2.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers3.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroup2.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     if($adGroupMembership3 -like $($adGroup3.Name))
         {
         "$adUsers3.Name is alreay a member of group $($adGroup3.Name)"
         }
      else
         {
         "Adding Active Directory user $($adUsers3.Name) the the global security group $($adGroup3.Name)"       
         Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers3.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($adGroup3.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop   
         }
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsers3.Name) to next year level"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsers3.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $ou3   
     }

foreach($adUsers2 in $adUserIds1)
     {
     $adGroupMembership2 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsers2.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc
     $adGroup2 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName2
     $radGroup1 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName1

     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsers2.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroup1.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers2.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroup1.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     if($adGroupMembership2 -like $($adGroup2.Name))
         {
         "$adUsers1.Name is alreay a member of group $($adGroup2.Name)"
         }
      else
         {
         "Adding Active Directory user $($adUsers2.Name) the the global security group $($adGroup2.Name)"
         Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers2.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($adGroup2.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop           
         }
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsers2.Name) to next year level"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsers2.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $ou2   
     }

foreach($adUsers1 in $adUserIdsr)
     {
     $adGroupMembership1 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($adUsers1.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc
     $adGroup1 = Get-ADGroup $adGroupName1
     $radGroupr = Get-ADGroup $adGroupNamer
     "Removing Active Directory user $($adUsers1.Name) from the following MemerOf $($radGroupr.Name)"
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers1.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($radGroupr.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop
     if($adGroupMembership1 -like $($adGroup1.Name))
         {
         "$adUsers1.Name is alreay a member of group $($adGroup1.Name)"
         }
      else
         {
         "Adding Active Directory user $($adUsers1.Name) the the global security group $($adGroup1.Name)"
         Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Confirm:$false -Identity $($adUsers1.DistinguishedName) -MemberOf $($adGroup1.DistinguishedName) -Server $dc -ErrorAction Stop          
         }
     "Moving Active Directory user: $($adUsers1.Name) to next year level"
     Move-ADObject -Identity $($adUsers1.DistinguishedName) -TargetPath $ou   
     }
```

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a [mcve].

Comment: On your Move-ADObject commands, why do you not also use the -server $dc parameter?

Comment: Good point, I think I seriously just forgot to add it